# What is the windshield Heating Element (Thin Cable) for Aircraft or Rotorcraft?

Tags: aircraft-design

My question is related with the heated windshield employing the some type of heating elements. Very very thin metalic cables are in use between two glasses of windshield. I have searched but noting found about its material. Do you know any cable supplier provides/gives the below graph. I need a wire to use as a temperature sensor. The needed TCR coefficient temperature in °C is 0.0048-0.0050. Diameter can be between 0.02 – 0.03 mm. Would you have any suggestion to us about material / alloy?

[image]

Comment: Are you seeking a generic wire of these properties for a non aviation application, or is this to repair an aircraft? If you are after the part the electronics stack exchange may give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

[You can get generic, thin film style heating elements ready to go from various suppliers](https://www.omega.com/en-us/industrial-heaters/surface-heaters/flexible-heaters/khra-khlva-kha-series/p/KHA-406-5?gclsrc=aw.ds&gclid=CjwKCAiAlfqOBhAeEiwAYi43F3AH0Hct0zSukjs9KShzxGSgEgNhARxjdQZz5F3l7yIe5EM6q7SsiRoCn40QAvD_BwE). If you are replacing an existing windshield on a current aircraft you will need to source a proper, certified, windshield for that airframe which should have the wire already embedded in it.

[It seems that at least some of the elements are made of NiChrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome)